# Python GTK3 toolbar accelerator doesn't work

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm following the [Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/menus.html), and the accelerators I'm putting for the toolbar actions don't work.  Here's a program showing the problem, roughly based on that tutorial.  There's a menu action with `N` shortcut and a toolbar action with `X` shortcut.  Menu action's shorcut works, toolbar action's one doesn't, even though the actions are created identically.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

UI_INFO = """
<ui>
  <menubar name='TestMenubar'>
    <menu action='FileMenu'>
      <menuitem action='MenuAction' />
    </menu>
  </menubar>
  <toolbar name='TestToolbar'>
    <toolitem action='ToolbarAction' />
  </toolbar>
</ui>
"""

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Test")

        self.set_default_size(200, 100)

        action_group = Gtk.ActionGroup(name="test_actions")

        self.add_menu_action(action_group)
        self.add_toolbar_action(action_group)

        uimanager = self.create_ui_manager()
        uimanager.insert_action_group(action_group)

        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)

        menubar = uimanager.get_widget("/TestMenubar")
        box.pack_start(menubar, False, False, 0)

        toolbar = uimanager.get_widget("/TestToolbar")
        box.pack_start(toolbar, False, False, 0)

        self.add(box)

    def add_menu_action(self, action_group):
        action_filemenu = Gtk.Action(name="FileMenu", label="File")
        action_group.add_action(action_filemenu)


        action = Gtk.Action(name='MenuAction',
                            label="Menu action",
                            stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_NEW)
        action.connect('activate', self.on_menu_action)
        action_group.add_action_with_accel(action, 'N')

    def add_toolbar_action(self, action_group):
        action = Gtk.Action(name='ToolbarAction',
                            label="Press me",
                            stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_MEDIA_STOP)
        action.connect('activate', self.on_toolbar_action)
        action_group.add_action_with_accel(action, 'X')

    def on_menu_action(self, widget):
        print 'Menu action'

    def on_toolbar_action(self, widget):
        print 'Toolbar action'

    def create_ui_manager(self):
        uimanager = Gtk.UIManager()

        uimanager.add_ui_from_string(UI_INFO)

        self.add_accel_group(uimanager.get_accel_group())

        return uimanager

window = MyWindow()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

How can I make pressing `X` shortcut invoke the callback?

(The [reference for GTK+ 3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkActionGroup.html) say that `add_action_with_accel` is deprecated, so there's surely a better way to create the accelerators, but the doc doesn't show the way, and I couldn't find a better tutorial.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced with the same problem. I asked a similar question on gtk 3 programming specific to gedit plugins [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594173/accel-not-working-in-gedit-3-plugin). I found that the menubar shortcuts are the only ones that work. So just introduce a menu item which does exactly what your tool item does. Preserve your tool item in order to provide flexibility to the user, but do not assign it any shortcut. i.e. `add_action`, not `add_action_with_accel` would be enough to add it to the action group.